# In python print("backslash \") produces error but print("backslash \ ") doesn't produce error

Tags: python

In python `print("backslash \")` produces error but `print("backslash \ ")` doesn't produce error.

in `print(backslash \")` there is no space between \ and ".
and this produces a `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

whereas if i give a space between the \ and " , then there in no error. Why?

few more examples

```
print(" this is double backslash \\\sad ")
```

the above statement doesn't produce any error, and it generates the output as:-

```
this is a single backslash \\sad
```

and I get the same output on writing this :-

```
print(" this is a single backslash \\\\sad ")
```

Here I have escape each `\` separately, so this is working but why the previous one is working?

Comment: Why? Because you're not escaping the `"` then.

Comment: o sorry for that part of question..!! but what's the reason for the print of \\ ?

Comment: First slash escapes the second one and `\s` has no special meaning, hence `\\\s` becomes `\\s`.

Comment: Do you understand what backslashes in strings *actually do*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank's for your concern, I understood what backslash does but i didn't know much backslash in strings. If you can tell then ofcourse that will help me somehow. I'm new to programming that's why facing much problems. :)

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay then have a look at e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals, which explains how the string literals work

Comment: o yes..!! I have thoroughly gone through that. Thank's

Comment: The problem is the same for ordinary string literals as for raw string literals, and with the same underlying cause. So this is effectively a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\` character is the *escape sequence* character. `\"` escapes a quote as *part of the string value*, rather than a delimiter that signals the start or end of a string.

By adding a space, you produced a non-existing escape sequence, and the `\` is interpreted as a literal backslash instead.

See the [string literals documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> The backslash (`\`) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

A `\` without a *recognised* escape sequence is always a plain `\` however. See the documentation for recognised sequences.

Note that this also means you need to be able to escape the escape sequence; for that reason `\\` produces a single backslash literal. That way you can include `\\n` in a string and that is interpreted as one `\` character and `n`, while `\n` produces a newline character.

Comment: but what's the reason for the print of \\ ?

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay: you need a way of escaping the escape, so ``\\`` produces one backslash. `\s` is not a valid escape, so produces a ``\`` and `s`.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you `print("backslash \")` you are escaping the last `"` so therefore you get an error.. more info on escape chars: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html

Comment: sorry for that part of question..!! but what's the reason for the print of \\ ?

Comment: a single \ escapes the character on its right. When there is a space after '\' you are escaping the space when there is no space you are escaping " character and the first " requires the closing "... make sense?